# when to apply $scope.apply and What is $$phase here?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, apply

I am writing custom event directive for keydown.

```
Error: $apply already in progress
```

Probably like the following implementation

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest')
    this.$eval(fn);
  else<br>
    this.$apply(fn);
};
```

Comment: What is your directive code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be wary calling `$apply` or `$digest` manually, even using the "safe" approach.

If you want your changes to be applied, try using `$timeout` instead. This will delay the execution automatically until the next $digest cycle and hence will never result in a `$apply already in progress` error.